# invertible matrix that swaps between the columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have a matrix A: $$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 3 \\
        2 & 4  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

How do I find a matrix P(invertable matrix) that $A=P^{-1} * B  * P$
so I get a matrix B that swaps between the columns. I mean:  $$
        \begin{matrix}
        4 & 2 \\
        3 & 1  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They have different determinants, so forget it.

Comment: editing for a better example

Comment: Nevertheless, check out $A\cdot\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\cdot A$..

Answer (score 0):

@Berci provides a good example. In general, you can swap the columns of a matrix using a [permutation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), which will give you the swapped matrix whether it is left or right multiplied.

Comment: Yeah, berci got it right. Thank you guys for the help. If he would have posted it as an answer I would have accepted it

Comment: It doesn't answer the question as stated.